# Where is the place the status bar time gets updated?

Tags: android, time, statusbar

Got an issue, i have to display the AM & PM in english irrespective of the selected locale in android phone. Tried to findout the place where time gets updated in the status bar. But not able to find it.

Will any one please let me know which is the source code file in the android framework which is responsible for updating the time in status bar.

Thanks & Regards,
SSuman185

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of R & D. StatusBarManager.Java, StatusNarManagerService.java are the files for the status bar and will be in the framewroks/base/core/java/android/app path.

For the notification area see the NotificationManager.java (When we pull down the status bar).

SimpleDateFormat.java

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the AM/PM show, just have a look at Clock.java located at frameworks\base\packages\SystemUI\src\com\android\systemui\statusbar. 
 Study it and you would know how to make AM/PM shows. They are already there but not turned on.